# Problematic Employee

Tags: professionalism, new-manager, employee-engagement

A San Francisco (SFO) company wanted to have an Asian coverage and sent (forced) an Employee X to start its Asian setup, and after six months was supposed to return to SFO. Six months became three years for X.

He had hired JS as Manager to handle Asian Setup, as X liked the Asian place  and wanted to continue here, and also wanted to be the manager for the Asian Setup.
So X started putting all kinds of pressure on JS without providing any knowledge session, JS being a go getter, he worked hard, learnt most of them by himself. JS is now officially in charge for Asia and X returned to SFO.

JS had to hire another junior person just as a backup.

Now JS hired VG, VG initially did not show any interest in work,apart from that VG is hot headed, becomes agressive and defensive based on his mood. So JS had to yell at him, then JS reported this incident to his manager AA in America.He also apologized to VG and AA.

Now it is 9 months, VG apart from moving files , solving simple basic reruns (that too without thinking), has not yet shown any analytical activity so has to prove that he is a good hire. JS has tried many ways to improve VG,  since VG has focus issue, it is taking a long time get reasonable output.

JS reported about poor performance of VG to AA, but the way AA responded seems like JS has personal problem with VG (there is a certain degree of personal vengenance , but overall VG is profesionally unfit), but still there is problem with VG, which AA does not seems to be trusting based on previous experience encounter by JS.

Now JS is getting frustrated due to poor performance of VG, but not able to convince AA. Also AA is of the belief X trained JS correctly, but JS failed.

JS is good individual contributor, has managed the technical projects as technical PM, but personally not managed anyone.

JS has two options now:

1. Improve VG performance , which is going to full time job and nothing else will move , as VG is poor , not sure what tactics JS should do to make VG more responsible.
2. Make AA to agree to terminate VG ,but given the situation it seems it is backfiring on JS.

How to handle this scenario.

Comment: What is "NA", what is "KT", which country are you in? Please explain the abbreviations and add a country tag so people can provide more focussed answers.

Comment: Personally, I found it very exhausting to read. You seem to use commas where normally people would use full stops to mark the end of a sentence. It might be easier on readers to fix that. The easier it is to read, the more people you reach and the greater the chance that you reach the person that has a great answer for you.

Comment: @nvoigt edited now.

Comment: Still hard to read. It's difficult to tell who is doing what. It might help to add fake names: Alice, Bob, Charlie, Doris, etc

Comment: If you don't think someone is suitably capable, it's probably best you deal with it before 9 months elapses.

Comment: What is your role in this (if I had to guess, you're "JS")? What are you trying to achieve? You need to ask an actual question in your "question".

Comment: I'm not seeing what X's involvement contributes to the question here and can probably be eliminated.  I assume that JS reported an "incident" not an "accident".

Comment: What does "there is a % to it" mean?

Comment: The history is irrelevant. You have an underperforming employee. The Manager's first job is to manage them, advising them on how to get better. If you can show that you have made an honest attempt and they are still not performing at the level your company considers reasonable, you can defend firing them. That's the question here, and that's the answer; the rest is an attempt to assign blame.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is straight forward case of performance management. It has nothing to do with X and very little with AA.

JS should deploy standard performance management practices:

1. Set clear goals with quantitative metrics
2. Review progress frequently in 1:1 meetings. At least once a week, at this point twice a week is probably better
3. Identify the problem points: could be technical skills, work habits, organizational skills, communication problems. Once you go apply metrics & tracking consistently, the issues can be identified quickly.
4. Put corrective actions in place as needed: could be technical training, could be mentoring, could be organizational classes, etc.
5. Set targets for what is acceptable and track progress. If there is steady improvement and you think VG can get there, great. If not, you need to think about termination but now you have a lot of objective data to back your decision.

In short: JS needs to start behaving like a actual manager. That's not easy if this is your first management job. You can ask for help and training, if needed. But JS has made some mistakes: they hired VG which apparently was a bad decision and they yelled which is NOT an acceptable behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar, One more problem with VG is , hot headed , both defensive and aggresive.

Comment: Yelling us never the right answer. Active management is. Set clear, achievable goals, and make sure the employee knows they are being evaluated against those standards, with failure to deliver having negative consequences up to and including firing. Upper management will support you in this, if they have any clue. "Not responding aggressively to management direction" is certainly one of those goals, and failure to meet if is grounds for dismissal. In other words, act like a first-manager and actively manage your reports. If you can't, them you are at risk of failing your own next review.